# Integrating a product of to error functions and an exponential

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, error-function

I have the following integral that I need to solve.

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2})*\text{erf}(x-\delta)*\text{erf}(x-\gamma)dx$

I was hoping I could use this: [Integral of product of exponential function and two complementary error functions (erfc)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156047/integral-of-product-of-exponential-function-and-two-complementary-error-function)

Comment: Actually the case with $\delta=\gamma=0$ can be solved using 8.258 2) in http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~ib38/tmp/reading/Table_of_Integrals_Series_and_Products_Tablicy_Integralov_Summ_Rjadov_I_Proizvedennij_Engl._2.pdf

and 4.3-2 here: http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73B/jresv73Bn1p1_A1b.pdf. 

And since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{erf}(x)^2\text{exp}(-x^2/2)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^\infty \text{erf}(x)^2\text{exp}(-x^2/2)$.... the result is easy to get.

Comment: Sorry, the $\frac{1}{2}$ on the rhs of the last equation should be a $2$.

Comment: You're right. *Maple* can evaluate it, but *Mathematica* can't $($for some mysterious reason$)$.